# SQL - Selecting data from two tables and removing duplicates

Tags: sql, database, select

So I have two tables and I'm trying to display some data from both and remove the duplicates. Sorry, I'm new to SQL and databases. Here's my code

Table 1

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    customer_id VARCHAR2(5),
    customer_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
    customer_address VARCHAR2(150) NOT NULL,
    customer_phone VARCHAR2(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);
```

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE shop
(
    shop_id VARCHAR2(7),
    shop_address VARCHAR2(150) NOT NULL,
    customer_id VARCHAR2(7),
    PRIMARY KEY (shop_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer (customer_id)
);
```

I want to display everything from the SHOP table, and customer_id, customer_name from the CUSTOMER TABLE.

I've tried this so far, but it's displaying everything from both tables and I get two duplicate customer_id columns:

```
SELECT * 
FROM shop 
JOIN customer ON shop.customer_id = customer.customer_id 
ORDER BY customer_name;
```

Anyone able to help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Due to both tables has column customer_id, so you can show everything on shop table and only column customer_name from customer table

```
SELECT s.*, c.customer_name 
FROM shop s
JOIN customer c ON s.customer_id = c.customer_id 
ORDER BY c.customer_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct c.customer_id, c.customer_name, s.*
from customer c
inner join shop s on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
```

- To remove duplicates, you need to use `distinct` keyword
  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually list the columns you want. Using `*` will pull in every column from every table. SQL does not have any way of saying "select all columns except these...".

I hope you're only using `*` casually - it's a very bad idea to use `SELECT *` inside program code that then expects certain columns to exist in a particular order or with a certain name.

To save typing, you could use `*` for one of the tables and manually name the rest:

```
SELECT
    customer.*,
    shop.shop_id,
    shop.shop_address
FROM
    ...
```